# YH11068A overvoltage

Tags: power, dc

I bought this DC-DC boost converter YH11068A:

[image]

I powered this with adapter 12 VDC - 4A and the output was stable and it worked so great for a few days.

A week later I was working with it and I was surprised the output voltage it goes up to is 600 V when I set the resistor to give output 200 V.

So now when I set this module resistor to give an output lower than 200 V it works great but if I set it up 200 it goes to 600 V and even more!

Why?! And since the datasheet says it has an output overvoltage protection and I was working greatly!

Datasheet: https://dalmura.com.au/static/YH11068A.pdf

Comment: Please link the proper pdf data sheet.

Comment: Edited, sorry my bad

Comment: 600 V ... when not loaded ... Don't do that, you should "overload" the output transistor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem is with the feedback compensation. The design seems to have a very low cross-over frequency (between 10 and 20 Hz), resulting in very low phase margins, which causes instability. Light loads are the most troublesome . You can't have the same loop gain over the whole voltage range. As the voltage increases, the loop gain should increase accordingly. If you run some AC transfer simulations on the [**circuit**](https://forum.retrotechnique.org/t/module-chinois-yh11068a/35077) provided for the yh11068a model on the web, you will see the problem. We ran some physical gain/phase sweeps on several units, and it confirmed the control loop problems.

There are lots of complaints from users that see the voltage overshoot randomly. Some shortcuts have been taken in the control loop design unfortunately.

"***I have fried two of those and have the impression that the voltage feedback of the booster sometimes doesn't work. The voltage hits nearly 600V and destroys the 400V capacitor in seconds.***" From DIY Audio

***"I powered this thing up with a 12v power supply and the voltage shot up to over 1kv, before I could even adjust the voltage the capacitor blew up..."*** From Amazon customer review

[image]

We have designed a similar product for a client, and the response curves are shown as comparison.

[image: Gain/Phase 390V]

[image: Gain/Phase 45V]

[image: Startup 390V]

[image: Startup Zoomed-in]

[image: Good control loop]

[image: 45V switched]

[image: 45V Z]

We also have another version under development to operate at 800 V.

[image: DCDC 800dev]

[image: DCDC 800]

Comment: Can you show the circuit diagram you have used to get these results?